# how to change already using gerrit application's auth type to OAUTH from OPENID 2.0

Tags: git, gerrit

we have a internal configured gerrit server. Here it used OPENID 2.0. Is there any way to change this openid to oauth? if so tell me the steps.

Answer (score 0):

We did that update recently. Which version of Gerrit do you use?

If you're using <=2.10, at first, you have to upgrade Gerrit to 2.11. See https://gerrit.googlesource.com/gerrit/+/master/ReleaseNotes/ReleaseNotes-2.11.txt for the upgrading details.